# Syfmony Embedded classes for entity - fieldMappings inheritance

Tags: symfony, inheritance, doctrine, embeddable

I've got the following issue and i can't found on the entire internet what should be the solution..

I've created a class named IdColumn and i want this class to be used in every entity of my project due to standardise reasons.

```
#[ORM\Embeddable]
class IdColumn
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(name: "id", type: "integer", options:["unsigned" => true])]
    protected int $id;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

After that i've created my entity like following and used the IdColumn

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: MyClassRepository::class)]
class MyClass
{
    #[ORM\Embedded(class: IdColumn::class, columnPrefix: false)]
    protected int $id;
```

The problem is that SF and Doctrine returns the fieldMappings of this entity for column $id as 'id.id' . So every time if i want to do a query, or insert something i've got to use that 'id.id' statement.

The question:
Is possible to overwrite the fieldMappings in symfony ? Or to use the last class property? I've got this issue also with another properties that are make from 3 classes and returns a fieldMappings like 'myFirstClassProperty.mySecondClassProperty.myFinalClassProperty'.

I've looked into Doctrine documentation and Symfony but no one ever discussed about fieldMappings issue with embeddable.

In the first place, also the column name was like id_id but the column_prefix: false resolved this issue.

Thank you :).

Note:
Using Symfony 6.2 and Doctrine 2.13

Comment: Have you tried using [Traits](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php). Example using it with an entity [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-traits-doctrine-entities/)..

Comment: I'am using embedded because IdColumn class extends an AbstractIntegerClass, and so on.. So basically all the Column object extends some other objects from a contract.

Comment: To be honest, i strongly advise you to not go in this way. If you want reusable column, trait are the best to do that. Like TimestampableEntity trait for the createdAt  / Updatedat behavior with lifecycle update . 
But in your case, you even do it for id column in the fear of having different id definition in the futur. I understand that but the way you're going gonna make you an hard to maintain project. Since all your entity gonna be "linked" to each other since they share the same definition. So if you do a change on one embedable, all your database gonna need to change

Comment: Agree with that but .. if you have a column definition.. let's say color - you will have the expectation that color as column to be string - with length of 50 in each table you will use it, so if you need to change somewhere, you will want to change everywhere, so it's kind of expected result to link all entities to same objects. Also keep in mind that i have some objects with some validations. When i want to create an object for my entity, i would like to be validated with the object's validations..